# cgi script can't get html form fields

Tags: html, cgi, python-3.4

I have WAMP server set up for python cgi. But, I couldn't grab values from html form. I have marked where I get the error in python file. If I remove that line error goes.

HTML:

```
<body>

<h1>Fill out this form</h1>

<form action="test.py" method="POST">
     Enter your name: <input type="text" name="name">
     Enter age: <input type="text" name="age">

     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
```

test.py:

```
#!C:\Python34\python

import cgitb
import cgi


form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print("""
<h1>Thanks for registering</h1>
""")

print("<p> form["name"].value")  # <--- If i remove this line the error goes
```

Error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable     to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: Looks like a syntax error to me

Comment: @BryanWay whats the error? i copy pasted everything from python doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntax error. From this line:

```
print("<p> form["name"].value")
```

The string that's being printed is getting terminated early. Change it to:

```
print("<p>" + form["name"].value + "</p>")
```

Comment: ohh i didn't paid attention to that closing paragraph tag. thanks a lot. Now i won't trust in copy pasting google docs code to the interpreter.